# Stringified JSON has unwanted double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, stringify

I am making a weather forecasting website, and querying the API returns a pure JSON response. However, when I stringify the data and append it to an element, to put it on the webpage, it has double quotes, see here:

[image: see here]

How would I be able to remove the double quotes from the stringified JSON text in order for it to display like a normal webpage? My code is below:

```js
$.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22canberra%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys",
  function(data) {
    $("body")
      .append("Count: " + JSON.stringify(data.query.count)); 
    $("#heading")  
      .append(JSON.stringify(data.query.results.channel.title));
  },
"json");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Yahoo Weather for Canberra</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="heading"></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

All help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If title is already a string, there is no reason to stringify it in the first place.  Just use it.  The same goes for the count if it is already a number.

Comment: Simple don't stringify... :) .. just use `.append(data.query.results.channel.title)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll tell you what happens!

Comment: :).. well you don't have to ask for upvote. Make sure your question is clear and specific. You will get upvotes. Ok and I am not the one to downvote you BTW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't stringify things that are not objects.  Just use them.

```js
$.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22canberra%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys",
function(data) {
  $(document.body).append("Count: " + data.query.count); 
  $("#heading").append(data.query.results.channel.title);
}, "json");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Yahoo Weather for Canberra</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="heading"></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

`.append(JSON.stringify(data.query.results.channel.title));`

to

`.append(data.query.results.channel.title);`

because data.query.results.channel.title is already a string.

`console.log(typeof data.query.results.channel.title);` // string

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify provides the string representation of a JSON object.

You don't need to stringify the values with  primitive datatypes.

So the code you should be using is:

```
$.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22canberra%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys", function(data) {
     $("body").append("Count: " + data.query.count); //  2pm
     $("#heading").append( data.query.results.channel.title);
}, "json");
```